# I want to use server's ID followed by if-else blocks for assigning different roles in multiple servers when users join

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

Following is the code using which I cannot have control for assigning different roles across multiple servers:

```
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name='Role Name')
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

^This code is working fine, however I want to add one more stage which would match server ID using 'if-else' and if the server is correct, then assigning roles should take place individually...

I don't know certain attributes/methods for doing this I want to implement Something like this:

```
    if serverID = = (ID)
      role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name='Role Name')
      await member.add_roles(role)
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `Member.guild` you can use that to get the `guild.id`

```py
async def on_member_join(member):
    if member.guild.id == 123:
        #code
```